# Custom Slider in Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, slider, flutter-layout, seekbar-thumb

I'm having problems to create a custom slider on flutter. The image is the following one:

[image]

I know how to create it on XML on Android, but with flutter, I'm having problems. In the Slider class constructor is not a parameter for slider background from assets or a thumb from assets.

Anyone could please help me/ guide me, about how to achieve the expected result? Thanks.

Comment: sse [SliderTheme](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/SliderTheme-class.html) - the docs say: *"A slider theme describes the colors and shape choices of the slider components."*

Comment: yes, but cannot find a way to insert files as png or jpg to the background or the thumb, I just found canvas examples.

Comment: @pskink yes, I have zero experience working with canvas, doing this kind of design seems very hard for me, I used to always put the complete images on the views. Or maybe exist a tool to transform the icons to canvas? I also have it on SVG and XML.

Comment: no, there is not such tool: you have to use `Canvas` API

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to create a custom Slider in Flutter. You can visit this [guide](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-sliders-demystified-4b3ea65879c) to learn more. Then you can use `RotatedBox` if you need the Slider to be vertical.

[image: Demo]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Custom Slider Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RotatedBox(quarterTurns: 1, child: SliderWidget()),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomSliderThumbCircle extends SliderComponentShape {
  final double thumbRadius;
  final int min;
  final int max;

  const CustomSliderThumbCircle({
    required this.thumbRadius,
    this.min = 0,
    this.max = 10,
  });

  @override
  Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) {
    return Size.fromRadius(thumbRadius);
  }

  @override
  void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset center, {
    Animation<double>? activationAnimation,
    Animation<double>? enableAnimation,
    bool? isDiscrete,
    TextPainter? labelPainter,
    RenderBox? parentBox,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    TextDirection? textDirection,
    required double value,
    double? textScaleFactor,
    Size? sizeWithOverflow,
  }) {
    final Canvas canvas = context.canvas;

    final paint = Paint()
      ..shader = LinearGradient(
        colors: [
          const Color(0xFF00c6ff),
          const Color(0xFF0072ff),
        ],
      ).createShader(Rect.fromCircle(
        center: Offset.fromDirection(0.0, 1.0),
        radius: 1.0,
      ));

    Paint paintBorder = new Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 3.0;

    canvas.drawCircle(center, thumbRadius * .9, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(center, thumbRadius * .9, paintBorder);
  }

  String getValue(double value) {
    return (min + (max - min) * value).round().toString();
  }
}

class SliderWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final double sliderHeight;
  final int min;
  final int max;
  final fullWidth;

  SliderWidget(
      {this.sliderHeight = 48,
      this.max = 10,
      this.min = 0,
      this.fullWidth = false});

  @override
  _SliderWidgetState createState() => _SliderWidgetState();
}

class _SliderWidgetState extends State<SliderWidget> {
  double _value = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double paddingFactor = .2;

    if (this.widget.fullWidth) paddingFactor = .3;

    return Container(
      width: this.widget.fullWidth
          ? double.infinity
          : (this.widget.sliderHeight) * 5.5,
      height: (this.widget.sliderHeight),
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular((this.widget.sliderHeight * .3)),
        ),
        gradient: new LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              const Color(0xFF00c6ff),
              const Color(0xFF0072ff),
            ],
            begin: const FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
            end: const FractionalOffset(1.0, 1.00),
            stops: [0.0, 1.0],
            tileMode: TileMode.clamp),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(this.widget.sliderHeight * paddingFactor,
            2, this.widget.sliderHeight * paddingFactor, 2),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            /// Optional Text for min value
            // Text(
            //   '${this.widget.min}',
            //   textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            //   style: TextStyle(
            //     fontSize: this.widget.sliderHeight * .3,
            //     fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            //     color: Colors.white,
            //   ),
            // ),
            SizedBox(
              width: this.widget.sliderHeight * .1,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Center(
                child: SliderTheme(
                  data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                    /// Color of the active track - left of the thumb slider
                    activeTrackColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(1),

                    /// Color of the inactive track - right of the thumb slider
                    inactiveTrackColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(1),

                    /// Track height
                    trackHeight: 10.0,
                    thumbShape: CustomSliderThumbCircle(
                      thumbRadius: this.widget.sliderHeight * .3,
                      min: this.widget.min,
                      max: this.widget.max,
                    ),
                    overlayColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(.4),
                    //valueIndicatorColor: Colors.white,
                    activeTickMarkColor: Colors.white,
                    inactiveTickMarkColor: Colors.red.withOpacity(.7),
                  ),
                  child: Slider(
                      value: _value,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _value = value;
                        });
                      }),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: this.widget.sliderHeight * .1,
            ),

            /// Optional Text for max value
            // Text(
            //   '${this.widget.max}',
            //   textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            //   style: TextStyle(
            //     fontSize: this.widget.sliderHeight * .3,
            //     fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            //     color: Colors.white,
            //   ),
            // ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```